# How to install tensorflowgpu-version with lower(compatible) version of cudatoolkit and cudnn

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

Every time I install `tensorflow-gpu` on anaconda its automatically installing `tensorflow-gpu` with
the most updated available version of `cudatoolkit` and `cudnn` evens if it's not compatible with graphic
card and cuda which I have already installed on my computer, which creates a big problem later on in
simulations.

For example I have RTX3060 and I am installing `tensorflow-gpu 2.5.0`, I have already installed
cuda 11.1 but when I install it with anaconda  as

```
"conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.5.0"
```

It will install `cudatoolkit 11.3.x`... and the most advanced available cudnn

Answer (score 0):

You can install `tensorflow-gpu` with the following commands with compatible `cudatoolkit` and `cudnn` versions.

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
#It is recommended to use pip to install TensorFlow since it is  officially released to PyPI.
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0
# Verify install:
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

For step-by-step instructions, please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions).